# How do you include read-only calculated properties in Breeze metadata?

Tags: breeze

I have a model class that has a property called Birthday with is a `DateTime?` property. I also have a calculated column that is read only that looks like this:

```
public int? RacingAge
{
  get
  {
    if (!Birthday.HasValue)
      return null;
    else
      return DateTime.Today.Year - Birthday.Value.Year;
   }
 }
```

When I run the query, this value comes back in the Json that is returned, but the property isn't part of the metadata so it doesn't get set.

What do I need to do to force this to get included in the metadata?

Comment: Excellent question. Exploring it. Stay tuned.

Comment: Take a look at [this StackOverflow question and answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16524073/handling-calculated-properties-with-breezejs-and-web-api) which shows how to get calculated properties into your model. Much has happened since Jan.