# Breeze: server computed properties to breeze computed observable

Tags: object, entity, breeze, computed-observable, computed-field

I am able to have breeze capture server computed properties using this code, gotten from [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16533551).

```
var yourTypeCtor = function () {
      this.calculatedProperty = ""; 
};

store.registerEntityTypeCtor("YourType", yourTypeCtor);
```

I have a computed property that returns an entity object. The entity type returned is part of the metadata. However, breeze returns this entity as an object, not an observable. Is it possible to configure breeze to return this object as an observable so that the object is updated based on the conditions of the computed properties that are defined on the server side?

Comment: You have entity A that has a navigation property to entity of type B, and B contains computed properties, and when A is saved, a new instance of B is created on the server and returned to the client?

Comment: You are right, but is it possible to have it update before saving, just like an observable will do? Also, breeze does not even recognnise the computed property to be an emtity type

Comment: Why can't you use a regular navigation property for this?  Declare the relationship between A and B in the metadata.